# jquery mobile dynamic php content

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, dynamic

I am creating a mobile extention to an existing php backend. Hence ive been trying out Jquery Mobile for this.

I am trying to generate dynamic content from php backend, sending stored local data to generate the desired results based on users id etc etc. It baffels me a bit that jqm isnt 'more' prepared out of the box for these types of use.

Anyhow, Ive been working with the following example to insert dynamic content inside a div area:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', "#orders",function () {

  var uid = localStorage.getItem('uid');
  var mobilecode = localStorage.getItem('mobilecode');
  var company = localStorage.getItem('company');

  $("#orders_data").load("orders_data.php", {uid: uid, mobilecode: mobilecode, company:company}, function(){
  $('#orders_data').trigger('create');
  });  

});
```

Here is an example of php backend. Top php files are db and site setup plus user validation/details from post data.

```
<?php

define("AJAX_HTML", true); 
require($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/config/init.php"); 
require("init_ajax_handler.php"); 

?>

<div id="accordion-orders" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="info">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
     <h3>Order ID</h3>

    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
     <h3>Order ID</h3>

    <p>Notes</p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

This method works and puts the dynamic content into #orders_data, but every 3 or 4 times it fails resulting in white screen where the content is supposed to be. The div is infact empty!. If i refresh its okay again. The same happends both from mobile testing and desktop testing.
The php backend is hardcoded for testing purposes so i knows it sends jqm formatted data every time, and all required post data are recieved by backend aswell.

Anyone have any idea why it fails sometimes ? Or have a better method for fetching php data into jqm ?

Most of all i would like to simply call a complete page 'orders.php' directly by menu triggering along with get or postdata, instead of updating divs.

Comment: can you post what HTML code you want to insert?

Comment: add the html code to your answer not as a reply...

Comment: SOLVED same day: problem was duplicate id #orders_data throughout site, switched to using classnames as identificators due to constant hassle and unexpected behaviour when working with id's in jqm.